# DataTables sorting not showing in descending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Please solve my problem. I want to show descending order. By default it is ascending order.

Please check my code-

**[datTable.js](http://myshowcam.com/TestSite/assets/data-tables/jquery.dataTables.js)**

**JS-**

```
<script href="http://myshowcam.com/TestSite/assets/data-tables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "Prev",
                "sNext": "Next"
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            'bSortable': false,
            'aTargets': [0]
        }]
    });
</script>
```

HTML-

```
<table class="table table-striped border-top" id="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="hidden-phone"> #ID </th>
      <th class="hidden-phone"> Username </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>chinu</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Debakanta</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Sanjib</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Above code by default i am getting `asc` record in the first column.

I want to customize above code. Need `desc`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add an [order](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) property to your table configuration. Your version of datatables doesn't support the [order](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) property. I'd recommend updating to the latest version of datatables if you can.

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
    order: [
        [0, 'desc']
    ]
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n38zywmm/). (note: I had to comment out the paginate property, uncomment it in your code)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
   "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]] // Sort by first column descending
} );
```

http://live.datatables.net/pacirato/1/edit

Comment: While providing a solution, you should explain why this would work or create another snippet providing how it fits into the code for the question.